# Android: layout with match_parent shall take the space left or share

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, fill-parent

I have a horizontal Linear Layout, containing two Layouts. I want the **right** layout to be as wide as the content (wrap_content). The **left** layout shall fill remaining space.

I tried with "match_parent" on the left layout(Relative Layout) and "wrap_content" on the right layout(Linear Layout), but the left layout takes **all** the space.

How can I solve this problem, that the left Layout just takes the space, which remains, not everything. Like letting the right layout take its space first.

EDIT::
Sorry, I wanted to post a picture, but couldnt, here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff27"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Relative Layout on the left takes ALL the space (the screen becomes green).
I want the Relative Layout to take the width, which remains from the LinearLayout, so you can see the button in the Layout.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code.

Comment: k, done. I hope it can help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android lays out views in the order in which they appear in the layout file. Therefore, your first view fills up all available space before the second view has a chance to take up any space. One workaround is to make your root layout a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, letting you put the right-side view first. Another is to leave the root LinearLayout and use the layout_weight attribute. On your first view, instead of `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, try `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: NICE, it works! Thanks! I tried the second solution by setting the width to 0dp and weight to 1!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff27"></RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```